# Sidebar stick to bottom (CSS or JS) - reset to top

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

Added snippet like requested but the css was designed for broader screen.

```js
const target = document.getElementById('content_left');
const init_rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
const index_height = init_rect.height;
console.log('initial height '+index_height); 
const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

window.onscroll = function()
    {
        const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const buffer = document.getElementById('buffer');
        
        console.log("viewport :"+viewportHeight);
        console.log("top: "+rect.top);
        console.log("bottom: "+rect.bottom);
        console.log("height: "+rect.height);
        top_diff = viewportHeight-index_height;
        console.log("topdiff: "+top_diff);
        if (rect.bottom < viewportHeight) 
            {
                console.log('passed');
                target.style.position='fixed';
                buffer.style.display='block';
                buffer_position = buffer.getBoundingClientRect();
                target.style.left=buffer_position.left+"px";
                target.style.bottom="0px";
                
            }       
    };
```

```css
    body
        {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
      
            width:100%;
            height;100%;
      
            background-color:#777b87;

            min-height: 100%;
            overflow-x:hidden;
            
            display:flex;
            flex-flow:row wrap;
            justify-content:center;
            max-width:1920px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        #content_left
                {
                    display:flex;
                    flex-flow:column nowrap;
                    width:300px;
                    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
          position:sticky;
          height:100%;
          bottom:0px;
                }

#content
        {   
            width:calc(100% - 60px);
            
            padding:20px;
            margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top:10px;
            z-index:100;
            border:1px solid #CCC;

      width: calc(100% - 350px);
      max-width: 850px;
}
#buffer
{
  display:none;
  height:1px;
  width:300px;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="buffer">
  </div>
  <div id="content_left">
    <div class="sub_container">
      START START START START  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST 
    </div>
     <div class="sub_container">
      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST
    </div>
        <div class="sub_container">
      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST  END  END END END END END END END   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc   aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb cccccaaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc      aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc    aaaaaa bbbbb ccccc     
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to build a page with a left sidebar that becomes sticky when the viewport reaches the bottom of that sidebar. I have tried using position:sticky but each time the viewport was reaching the bottom of the sidebar, the stickiness worked but the sidebar was set to top:0px.

I have then tried to do the same with javascript, I can trigger the changes when the bottom of the sidebar crosses the viewport but again, the sidebar gets positioned from the top and is not entirely visible. I suspect it has something to do with height settings but I can't isolate it.

I have created a codepen to show what is happening once content in inserted into the page:

https://codepen.io/LaurentWi/pen/OJwbrRw (it's too long to be copied here)

The html without the content is the following:

```
<body>
  <div id="buffer">
  </div>
  <div id="content_left">
    <div class="sub_container">
    </div>
    <div class="sub_container">
    </div>
    <div class="sub_container">
    </div>
 </div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I have used a "buffer" div to keep the rest of the screen in the right position when content_left leaves the flow.

The CSS looks like this:

```
    body
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
  
        width:100%;
        height;100%;
  
        background-color:#777b87;

        min-height: 100%;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        
        display:flex;
        flex-flow:row wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        max-width:1920px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #content_left
            {
                display:flex;
                flex-flow:column nowrap;
                width:300px;
                padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
      position:sticky;
      height:100%;
      bottom:0px;
            }

#content
    {   
        width:calc(100% - 60px);
        
        padding:20px;
        margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top:10px;
        z-index:100;
        border:1px solid #CCC;

  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  max-width: 850px;
}
#buffer
{
  display:none;
  height:1px;
  width:300px;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

And finally the JS:

```
const target = document.getElementById('content_left');
const init_rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
const index_height = init_rect.height;
console.log('initial height '+index_height); 
const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

window.onscroll = function()
{
    const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const buffer = document.getElementById('buffer');
    
    console.log("viewport :"+viewportHeight);
    console.log("top: "+rect.top);
    console.log("bottom: "+rect.bottom);
    console.log("height: "+rect.height);
    top_diff = viewportHeight-index_height;
    console.log("topdiff: "+top_diff);
    if (rect.bottom < viewportHeight) 
        {
            console.log('passed');
            target.style.position='fixed';
            buffer.style.display='block';
            buffer_position = buffer.getBoundingClientRect();
            target.style.left=buffer_position.left+"px";
            target.style.bottom="0px";
            
        }       
};
```

I would prefer a solution without JS if you have one but JS is fine as long as it is only vanilla JS.

I suspect that the problem is coming from the height because when the JS display the height of content_left, the value is ok until the element is in position fixed where the height value becomes the viewport height (see console in codepen). I have tried avoiding this by forcing the initial height but it didn't work either because the initial height (see code in JS) was always smaller than the reality. I'm a bit puzzled.

Any idea?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: @starball sure, I was aware it was possible, I have added the code to the snippet but the css was meant for a bigger screen, the output is not optimal.

Comment: stack snippets can be expanded for fullscreen. You could just say that your snippet is best viewed in fullscreen mode in your question post.